# Image spanning to the next div when window size is decreased

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

So, I have to create this Page where in you get text alongside image displayed as seen in here

[image: Before minimising]

But , on minimising the window size the image gets overlapped as seen here

[image: After minimising]

```
  <div class="header1">
  <div class="col-md-8">
     <h4 class="hedtext">Name</h4>
     </br>
     <h4 class="hedtext">Address</h4>
     </br>
     <h4 class="hedtext">Contact Number</h4>
     </br>
     <h4 class="hedtext">Fax</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/248797/pexels-photo-248797.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500" class="pull-right img1">
  </div>
</div>
```

and Here is the css

```
.hedtext {
padding-top:10px;
margin-bottom: -19px;
line-height: 2pt; 
font-size: 13px;
font-weight: 750;
float: left;
}

.header1 {
 border: 1px solid black;
 height: 150px;
 }

.img1 {
width: auto;
height: 130px;
padding :10px;
}
```

Also, using bootstrap 3 . All i want is that the image goes side by side the text on minimising the window size .

Comment: you tag bootstrap -4 but in answer wrote bootstrap-3 what do you use?

Comment: You should tag bootstrap-3 instead of bootstrap-4. Also if you intend to use `col-md-*`, you need a `row` class as parent.

Comment: The problem here is that you forced the image to a specific width, so that it will eventually become wider than the col-md-4 it is in …

Answer (score 1):

First you have forgot to add the **.row** class div which bootstrap requires to wrap around the columns to work correctly.

I removed .pull-right and instead just added text-right to the column. You can also use floats though or whatever to set the image to the right side however you wish.

```
<div class="header1 row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <h4 class="hedtext">Name</h4>
        </br>
        <h4 class="hedtext">Address</h4>
        </br>
        <h4 class="hedtext">Contact Number</h4>
        </br>
        <h4 class="hedtext">Fax</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 text-right">
        <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/248797/pexels-photo-248797.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500"
            class="img1">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You have to wrap `col` in `row`
2. Remove the `.hedtext` -  `float` (bootstrap worry about float)
3. Remove `.header1` `height: 130px;` (It the reason image out of border)

[See working code](https://jsfiddle.net/vkabsd10/)

```css
.hedtext {
  line-height: 2pt;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 750;
}
.row {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.img1 {
  width: auto;
  height: 130px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <h4 class="hedtext">Name</h4>
    <h4 class="hedtext">Address</h4>
    <h4 class="hedtext">Contact Number</h4>
    <h4 class="hedtext">Fax</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/248797/pexels-photo-248797.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500" class="img1">
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to add responsive class in div like `col-xs-*` for responsive

> do this for your solution

```
<div clss="row">
    <div class="header1">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-xs-8">
            <h4 class="hedtext">Name</h4>
            </br>
            <h4 class="hedtext">Address</h4>
            </br>
            <h4 class="hedtext">Contact Number</h4>
            </br>
            <h4 class="hedtext">Fax</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4">
            <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/248797/pexels-photo-248797.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500"
                 class="pull-right img1">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```